# Problem with the regex of Zend_Json prettyPrint

Tags: regex, json, zend-framework

I have a problem with the regex of Zend_Json::prettyPrint. 
When in my JSON response I have a string with a comma inside like

```
"stack, overflow"
```

the string is splited in two:

```
"stack,
overflow"
```

and I would like to have the string on the same line and not splited. In the file Zend/Json I found the regex:

```
$tokens = preg_split('|([\{\}\]\[,])|', $json, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

I don't arrive to correct the regex to avoid the split when there is a comma inside the double quote.

Here is the JSON for the test:

```
{ "test":"stack, overflow" }
```

I hope somebody will be able to help me.

Thanks in advance,

Maxime.

Comment: On a side note: if all that class does it formatting 'pretty' json (indents etc.), you're imho better of decoding it & write a pretty easy recursive function.

Comment: Do you want the double quotes in the output? If not you can just add that to the preg_split and remove the comma. |([\{\}\]\["])| although you'll capture a lot of white space as well as what you want. If you want double quotes, everything inside, end quotes that's all inside brackets, preg_split probably isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I found a solution not a real clean solution but it works. I would like to do it with regular expression in the future.

I just count the number of double quotes without the double quotes escaped, and when the number of quotes are pair and the split is a comma, I add a line break.

You can watch the helper here:
http://gist.github.com/483311